# How do I include SVG file used as featured image?

Tags: php, svg

I'm new,
can I use include() or get_template_part to load an SVG file uploaded as featured image directly in the HTML page?

I need to animate the svg images, but i need to easily change the image on each page.

I have tried this code but does't work, I can't find the right path, I can load only the svg images in the same folder.

```
    $domain = get_site_url();
    $svg_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID());
    $svg = str_replace( $domain, '', $svg_url );

    echo $svg; //only for read the url

    get_template_part($svg);
    // or
    inlcude $svg;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't need the URL but the server path to the file, you can get it with [`get_attached_file`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_attached_file/) function, passing any WordPress attachment ID as a parameter. Then you need to load the contents of that SVG file directly, via [`file_get_contents`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php) function and echo it out to the page.

```php
$thumbnail_id   = get_post_thumbnail_id( get_the_ID() );
$thumbnail_path = get_attached_file( $thumbnail_id );
echo file_get_contents( $thumbnail_path );
```

Comment: Perfect solution! can I also use it for the logo?

Comment: @AlessioPaoletti Yes, any SVG you want to load directly if you have the attachment ID.